# javax.crypto.BadPaddingException on decrypting using keystore in android

Tags: android, kotlin, cryptography, android-keystore

I am trying to use android keystore for encrypting and decrypting data and I am able to do it for single operation, however if I want to encrypt multiple keys and decrypt them, I am getting javax.crypto.BadPaddingException for all the keys except for the last one. only the last is getting successfully decrypted.

Please help me find the issue

```
class MainActivity {
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_portfolio)

        saveDataInKeyStore()
        saveDataInKeyStore2()

        getDataFromKeyStore()
        getDataFromKeyStore2()
    }

private fun saveDataInKeyStore() {
        val secureText = "testfirststringusername"
        keyStoreManager.saveData("username", secureText.toByteArray(),
            successAction = {
                printData(it.toString())
            },
            failedAction = {
                printData("failed")
            })
    }

    private fun getDataFromKeyStore() {
        keyStoreManager.getData("username",
            successAction = {
                printData(String(it))
            },
            failedAction = {
                printData("failed")
            })
    }

    private fun saveDataInKeyStore2() {
        val secureText = "testfirststringpassword"
        keyStoreManager.saveData("password", secureText.toByteArray(),
            successAction = {
                printData(it.toString())
            },
            failedAction = {
                printData("failed")
            })
    }

    private fun getDataFromKeyStore2() {
        keyStoreManager.getData("password",
            successAction = {
                printData(String(it))
            },
            failedAction = {
                printData("failed")
            })
    }

    private fun printData(msg: String) {
        println("testing keystore status: " + msg)
    }
}


class KeyStoreManager(val sharedPreferencesManager: SharedPreferencesManager) {

    private val keyStore: KeyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(KEYSTORE).apply { load(null) }

    private fun getKey(): Key? = keyStore.getKey(KEY_NAME, null)

    fun saveData(dataKey: String, dataValue: ByteArray, successAction: (ByteArray) -> Unit, failedAction: () -> Unit) {
        try {
            val secretKey = createKey()
            val cipher = getEncryptCipher(secretKey)
            handleEncrypt(cipher, dataKey, dataValue, successAction)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            failedAction()
        }
    }

    private fun createKey(): Key {

        val keyGenerator = KeyGenerator.getInstance(ALGORITHM, KEYSTORE)
        val keyGenParameterSpec =
            KeyGenParameterSpec.Builder(KEY_NAME, KeyProperties.PURPOSE_ENCRYPT or KeyProperties.PURPOSE_DECRYPT)
                .setBlockModes(BLOCK_MODE)
                .setEncryptionPaddings(PADDING)
                .build()

        keyGenerator.init(keyGenParameterSpec)
        return keyGenerator.generateKey()
    }

    private fun getEncryptCipher(key: Key): Cipher =
        Cipher.getInstance(keyTransformation()).apply { init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key) }

    private fun handleEncrypt(
        cipher: Cipher,
        dataKey: String,
        dataValue: ByteArray,
        successAction: (ByteArray) -> Unit
    ) {
        val iv = cipher.iv
        val encryptedData = cipher.doFinal(dataValue)
        saveEncryptedData(dataKey, encryptedData, iv)
        // println("testing saving encrypted data $dataKey cipher= $cipher iv= $iv")
        successAction(encryptedData)
    }

    private fun saveEncryptedData(dataKey: String, dataEncrypted: ByteArray, initializationVector: ByteArray) {

        sharedPreferencesManager.putString(dataKey, Base64.encodeToString(dataEncrypted, Base64.DEFAULT))
        sharedPreferencesManager.putString(
            INITIALIZATION_VECTOR + dataKey,
            Base64.encodeToString(initializationVector, Base64.DEFAULT)
        )
    }

    fun getData(dataKey: String, successAction: (ByteArray) -> Unit, failedAction: () -> Unit) {
        try {
            val secretKey = getKey()
            val initializationVector = getInitializationVector(dataKey)
            if (secretKey != null && initializationVector != null) {
                val cipher = getDecryptCipher(secretKey, initializationVector)
                // println("testing getting decrypted data $dataKey cipher= $cipher iv= $initializationVector")
                handleDecrypt(dataKey, cipher, successAction)
            } else {
                failedAction()
            }
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            println("testing getting data from keystore manager failed: " + e)
            failedAction()
        }
    }

    private fun getInitializationVector(dataKey: String): ByteArray? {
        val iv = sharedPreferencesManager.getString(INITIALIZATION_VECTOR + dataKey, "")
        return when {
            !"".equals(iv) -> Base64.decode(iv, Base64.DEFAULT)
            else -> null
        }
    }

    private fun getDecryptCipher(key: Key, iv: ByteArray): Cipher =
        Cipher.getInstance(keyTransformation()).apply { init(Cipher.DECRYPT_MODE, key, IvParameterSpec(iv)) }

    private fun handleDecrypt(dataKey: String, cipher: Cipher, successAction: (ByteArray) -> Unit) {
        val encrypted = getEncryptedData(dataKey)
        val data = cipher.doFinal(encrypted)
        successAction(data)
    }

    private fun getEncryptedData(dataKey: String): ByteArray? {
        val encryptedData = sharedPreferencesManager.getString(dataKey, "")
        return when {
            !"".equals(encryptedData) -> Base64.decode(encryptedData, Base64.DEFAULT)
            else -> null
        }
    }

    private fun keyTransformation() = listOf(ALGORITHM, BLOCK_MODE, PADDING).joinToString(separator = "/")
}
```

output I am getting

```
I/System.out: testing keystore status: [B@283eda1
I/System.out: testing keystore status: [B@8e7095
I/System.out: testing getting data from keystore manager failed: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException
I/System.out: testing keystore status: failed
I/System.out: testing keystore status: testfirststringpassword
```

Expected output

```
I/System.out: testing keystore status: [B@283eda1
I/System.out: testing keystore status: [B@8e7095
I/System.out: testing getting data from keystore manager failed: javax.crypto.BadPaddingException
I/System.out: testing keystore status: testfirststringusername
I/System.out: testing keystore status: testfirststringpassword
```

Comment: `[B@283eda1` that's not a good sign.

Comment: Perhaps someone can explain: 1) What line the exception is coming from, 2) Where the output is coming from, 3) how the expected output differs from the actual output, 4) what the cipher transform string is. Please make this an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)